# Why doesn't the CSS calc() function work for me?

Tags: css

I learned about the CSS function calc() and its awesome. I tried to use it like:

```css
#abc{width:calc(100%-20px)}
```

But the problem with this function is that it doesn't work. I tested this code IE9 and Safari and it didn't work.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 60):

The operator `-` must be surrounded by spaces:

```css
#abc{width:calc(100% - 20px)}
```

Quoting [MDN info on `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc):

> Note: The `+` and `-` operators **must be surrounded by [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Whitespace)**. For instance, `calc(50% -8px)` will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length—an invalid expression—while `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a subtraction operator and a length. Likewise, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by an addition operator and a negative percentage.
>
> The `*` and `/` operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is both allowed and recommended.

The formal statement on this is in [clause 8.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax) of the CSS Values and Units Module Level 3 specification.

Answer (score 18):

All the modern browsers except Android's native browser support `calc()` which makes it easier to adopt. But do note that it can have a big impact on the layout and the consequent breaking of your design on unsupported browsers.

You should use it with a fallback declaration, so it doesn't break browsers which don't support it.

```
width: 500px; /** older browsers **/ 

width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px); /** Safari 6, Chrome 19-25 **/

width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px); /** FF 4-15  **/

width: calc(50% - 20px); /** FF 16+, IE 9+, Opera 15, Chrome 26+, Safari 7 and future other browsers **/
```

Answer (score 5):

It is supported by IE9, IE10 and Safari 6.0 (*using `-webkit-` prefix*). You can check whole support table here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: with modernizr you can check if the browser supports this feature and if it doesn't fallback to javascript or another style http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Is it just me or does it forget to mention to use the prefix on the caniuse page?

Answer (score 4):

IE9's implementation of the `calc()` method doesn't work on elements which are `display: table`.

You can work around this by wrapping a div around it (which is `display: block`) and making the width of the `display: table` element inside `width: 100%`. You apply the `calc`d width to the surrounding `div`.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your function to work you need to have **spaces between the operator sign**.

For example:

```
#abc{
  width: calc(100% - 20px)
}
```

The [calc() article](https://kolosek.com/css-calc/) provides a further detailed explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there should be spaces before and after `+` or `-`. You can also use `*` , `/`, and combine them. See example:

```css
.gen {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.nocalc {
  width: 50%;
}

.calc {
  width: calc(100% / 4 * 2 + 50px - 40px); 
  /* 50% + 10px */
}
```

```html
<div class="gen nocalc"></div>
<div class="gen calc"></div>
```

**It works** with `display: table`, but it **does not work** with `display: table-row`(row takes whole space) and does not work with `display: table-cell` (if one cell it takes whole space; if several - **each cell takes space according to its content**).

```css
.cont-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cont-2 {
 background-color: red;
 border: solid 1px black;
}

.width-m-50 {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
}

.tab-simple {
  display: table;
}

.tab {
  display: table;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.tab-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-1"> 
  <div class="cont-2 width-m-50"> 
    div with width: calc(100% - 20px);
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont-1"> 
  <div class="cont-2 tab-simple width-m-50"> 
    tab with width: calc(100% - 20px);
  </div>
</div>
<h3> tab with width 100% and two cells, 1-st with width calc(100% - 20px); 2-nd without: </h3>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tab-row"> 
      <div class="cont-2 tab-cell width-m-50"> 
        cell
      </div>
      <div class="cont-2 tab-cell"> 
        cell 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of *Modernizr* you can check csscalc support. Simply use *Modernizr.csscalc*. This function will return true if it is supported and false if it isn't.
In your case you would have this in your css :

```
#abc {  width:calc(100% - 20px); }
```

and in your *javascript* (I am using *jQuery* here)

```
if(!Modernizr.csscalc){
    $('#abc').width($(PARENT_EL).width() - 20)
}
```

BTW. It is better to style your elements with class names rather than ID. The ID of an element should only be used to target it through *javascript*.

Comment: Great answer for dealing with css width calc in Safari v5.1.7 :))

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces and also if you use preprocessor format it like this `calc(~"100% - 20px")` or it might not work.