# Safari not computing calc() values

Tags: javascript, css, safari, computed-style

I wonder if this is a bug or if there's a good workaround:

Only on Safari (using iOS Safari 8.1 and Safari 7.0.5 for the Dev Tools), the browser doesn't seem to have a calculated value for an an element with the style:

`.node { top: calc(39px - 100%); }`

it displays properly in the browser, but `window.getComputedStyle($('.node')).top` returns `null` and in fact the Computed Properties in Safari's dev tools also show `top: null`. If I change the style to a pixel value, the Computed Property shows correctly (i.e., `top: 400px`).

This is a problem for me because I'd like to use the computed style value in JavaScript calculations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS calc not working in Safari and fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443343/css-calc-not-working-in-safari-and-fallback)

Comment: This has always been buggy in safari. There are some alternatives here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443343/css-calc-not-working-in-safari-and-fallback

Comment: Fair enough. I found it strange that I didn't need a fallback for Safari >= 7, but it wasn't displaying the calculation that had clearly been done. I'll do it all in JS.